# How do I extract links from a dynamic page with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, dynamic

What I am trying to accomplish is to make mass downloading easier. The problem is, the links are within a page that opens up in front of the main page. I have to manual click the Library and then expand it.

Once it's expanded, I can ctrl + A then view source to copy and paste it to a txt so that a python script can go in and extract the links.

After using firebug I can see the div that is related to the library window.

```
<div id="mapLibrary" class="modal hide in" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
```

The links I want to grab and create a separate html (which I can do already) resides within the div

`class="libraryGrid" --> <table class="backgrid table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed available> --> <tbody> --> <tr id="subitem_#####" class="subitem"> --> etc etc`

This continues til it gets to the actual link. How in the world can I get something to grab the links directly without a user having to open the Library and expand.

The only thing that kind sucks in my situation is that alot of the tools available (e.g., BS4, selenium, etc) I cannot willingly download/install them.

What are my options?

Comment: Why are you using python for this? I mean, you've got a javascript tag. jQuery can do this in as little as 2 lines. Can you post a link to the page you're trying to parse?

Comment: The website is an imagery website https://evwhs.digitalglobe.com/myDigitalGlobe/map#11/26.5305/44.9094

Comment: well, it looks like you need to have an account to view that page, so I can't help. I would play around with jquery though. You can select all links with just `$('a')` and filter til you find the one you want with `filter()`. You could even use greasmonkey to execute the code when you navigate to that page to save yourself some copy/paste time.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the account deal. The reason I was leaning towards python was for the simple fact that it is relatively easy to work with. Hopefully I'll be approved to install beautifulsoup, which I'm under the impression that it is pretty robust for crawling/scrapping.

I'll look into the jquery route, it's been interesting learning what I can with this side project. Thanks for the information.

Comment: would you be willing to paste the source code of that page into a pastebin or something? maybe I can whip up something helpful if you provide the source and let me know which link you're trying to get.